# Homework help to rearrange formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Given the equation
$${V_m} = u(\ln {m_0} - \ln {m_8}) - g{t_f}$$
I need to solve for ${m_0}$
Here is what I have but it looks messy and I feel like there is sometihng wrong or a better way

1st attempt

$$\eqalign{
  & {V_m} = u(\ln {m_0} - \ln {m_8}) - g{t_f}  \cr 
  & {V_m} = u(\ln {m_0}) - u(\ln {m_8}) - g{t_f}  \cr 
  & {V_m} = u(\ln {m_0}) - u(\ln {m_8}) - g{t_f}  \cr 
  & {V_m} = u(\ln {m_0}) - u(\ln {m_8}) - g{t_f}  \cr 
  & u(\ln {m_0}) - u(\ln {m_8}) - g{t_f} - {V_m} = 0  \cr 
  & u(\ln {m_0}) - u(\ln {m_8}) - {V_m} = g{t_f}  \cr 
  & u(\ln {m_0}) = g{t_f} + u(\ln {m_8}) + {V_m}  \cr 
  & \ln {m_0} = (g{t_f} + u(\ln {m_8}) + {V_m}) \div u  \cr 
  & {e^{(g{t_f} + u(\ln {m_8}) + {V_m}) \div u}} = {m_0} \cr} $$

2nd attempt - think this looks a little better but still not there yet

$$\eqalign{
  & {V_m} = u(\ln {{{m_0}} \over {{m_8}}}) - g{t_f}  \cr 
  & {V_m} + g{t_f} = u(\ln {{{m_0}} \over {{m_8}}})  \cr 
  & {{{V_m} + g{t_f}} \over u} = \ln {{{m_0}} \over {{m_8}}}  \cr 
  & {e^{{{{V_m} + g{t_f}} \over u}}} = {{{m_0}} \over {{m_8}}}  \cr 
  & {m_8}{e^{{{{V_m} + g{t_f}} \over u}}} = {m_0} \cr} $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\ln(a) - \ln(b) = \ln \left(\frac{a}{b} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks @Kaj Hansen , I have edited with a second attempt. Is that correct or is there still a better way?

Comment: As bad as it still looks, at least it's better than the original.  I think that might be as good as you'll get though.